# sql server generate all select script (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm in the process of developing an application that allows users to select tables and columns, and choose join methods ( like inner, outer..) as well as aggregate functions sql (sum, avg..etc) for the purpose of generating reports from those selections.

What I did is append strings to build a request to an sql server. I think i'm wrong doing it this way because users can choose a lot of columns and that throws unexpected exceptions. Are there some ideas on a better way to go about this (not source code)?

Comment: Have you tried stored procedure? Write all select statement in SQL procedure and invoke that from code.

Answer (score 0):

As you have asked, `what is best way to manage query ( can contain sum,avg etc..) generated on server side and made those to execute on SQL server`, I am writing best possible suggestion for this. Consider that and follow your path.

If you have adhoc queries generated in server side, then definitely you can write those into SQL group of statements known as `Stored Procedure` . And this has following advantages.

1. More manageable, if same set of SQL blocks need in multiple places, then use this single procedure everywhere.
2. Secure - you don't have to set permission( like `select`) for multiple tables (`join`ing tables), instead just have `execute` permission for procedure.
3. Good Performance - `Execution Plan Caching and Reuse`

Source - http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/38178

Stored proc - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx

If you are new to `stored procedure` and want to know, how to use that in asp.net, here is tutorial for this - http://www.dbtutorials.com/advanced/using-stored-procedures-cs/